# How can a particle possess infinite potential energy in The Delta-Function Well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For $V(x)=-{a\delta(x)}$, a>0; there is only one bound state for which           ${\psi(x)}={\frac{2\pi\sqrt{m\alpha}}{h}}e^{-4\pi^2 m\alpha\vert x\vert/h^2}$; $E=-\frac {2\pi^2 m\alpha^2}{h^2}$. $\psi(x)$ is non-zero at x=0. Since V(x) is infinite at x=0 how can a particle possess infinite potential energy?

Comment: The Dirac delta potential is a mathematical idealization of a more realistic potential.

Comment: Can you, please, explain in a bit more detail?